# How can I remove an unwanted character from the main page's title?

Tags: title, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I'm working on this website: http://mel-mary-blog.fr/

Since the girls creating all the articles wanted a better SEO, I installed Yaost and did all the configuration I could without paying for the premium services.

They rapidly asked me what I wanted to separate the main title from the articles' title, and I choose this character: `—`

However, since the website doesn't have a slogan, the main title now looks like follows:

> Mel & Mary —

Which doesn't look good nor "pro" at all when you find the website when looking up for their website. There are however no problem with any other pages.

My question is: How do I remove this "dash" from the title only on the main page? (Preferably from the back office, but I can change it from the code if needed)

Comment: Go to SEO > Search Appearance, and on the General tab edit the Homepage Title. If you are using a Page as your front page edit that page and use the Yoast box to edit its title.

Comment: I don't have the "Search Appearence" link in SEO, but the Google account is also not linked. Is that the reason why?

Comment: No, you don't have to link anything, it's part of the Yoast SEO plugin. You may have to turn on some sort of "advanced" flag to get the menus. Please look to their help documentation and forum for support since it's plugin-specific. :) https://kb.yoast.com/kb/yoast-wordpress-seo-titles-metas-template-variables/